# OpenCV-Colour tracking output as coloured background

Tags: opencv

I'm working with the OpenCV library in XCode and doing a colour tracking application that draws lines from one point to the next. I was wondering if it's possible to put the output not as the video but as a white background. 
So instead of

```
cvShowImage("video",frame);
```

Is there a function that would show (backgroundcolour, frame)? 
**edit:**

I've added this code but since canvas is not an image it won't let me write on to it instead of frame.

```
cv::Mat canvas(320, 240, CV_8UC3, Scalar(255,255,255));

 IplImage* imgYellowThresh1 = GetThresholdedImage1(canvas);
cvAdd(&canvas,imgScribble,&canvas);
cvShowImage("video",&canvas);
```

So the erro is on the `GetThresholdedImage1` saying "no matching function for call to GetThresholdedImage1"

Answer (score 1):

No, not it such a simple way you proposed. The solution would be to create separate `Mat an`d draw the lines on it.

`cv::Mat canvas(rows, cols, CV_8U3C, Scalar(255,255,255)); //set size, type and fill color`

You would prepare this mat an the begining of code, and then use the draw functions on it. So instead of drawing the lines on `frame` you would draw on `canvas`.

EDIT:
There was slight misconception. The problem is you are using old C API. To learn about the latest C++ API, follow this tutorials:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

Comment: My problem is drawing on to the mat  "IplImage* imgYellowThresh1 = GetThresholdedImage1(canvas);" which is giving me an error because canvas is a mat not an image.

Comment: IplImage is from C API, my code is valid for new C++ API. Is there any reason for using C API instead of C++?

Comment: I was unaware I was using that. I followed a tutorial and thought it was C++ in openCV :/

Comment: so in C++ the image is a mat as well?

Comment: In C++ cv::Mat is generic matrix implementation, but is used for storing images as well.

I would suggest you to follow this tutorials, for the latest release:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

Comment: Thanks. I saw that you can convert from IplImage to mat. Could I this way just change the thresholded image to a mat? " Mat A(imgYellowThresh1, true);" 
CvMat* imgYellowThresh1 = GetThresholdedImage1(canvas);

Comment: I think it should be possible. I've never worked with IplImages, so I cannot assist you on this one.